# Using Tuples as Keys in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to programming so forgive me if anything doesn't make sense or if I word things incorrectly. I have a question about using tuples as dictionary keys.

First, I have the user input a number,

```
num = input("Enter a number here: ")
```

Then, I turn this number value into a tuple:

```
numTup = tuple(num)
```

Next, I create a dictionary connecting numerical keys to word values:

```
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
```

And finally, I want it to print the dictionary values that correspond to the keys in the tuple. I'm pretty sure this is where I'm getting it wrong.

```
print(numWords[numTup])
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do with this program is have it print each user inputted digit as a word, ie. 456 would turn into "four five six".

**The full (incorrect) script:**

```
num = input("Enter a number here: ")
numTup = tuple(num)
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
print(numWords[numTup])
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are turning these into tuples. The keys in your dict are strings, not numbers or tuples. The stuff you get from `input` is also a string. You can use it as a key directly, the way you've set it up, without converting it to anything.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're after, you want each character from the input to be used as a key. But you are trying to do dictionary lookup with the tuple itself as a key. So if a tuple is `('3', '1', '0')`, your lookup is looking for that exact key, not for the keys `3`, `1`, `0`. You need to iterate over the the values of the tuple and use those values (which are strings) as keys. Since your dictionary has strings for keys.

Comment: So, the tuple is actually superfluous here, you can simply iterate over the characters of the string you got as input. so `for digit in inputstring:` will start just such a loop. then in the loop you can just print `numWords[digit]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! Not sure what I was trying to do lol

Comment: Np. The missing bit was the iteration over the elements of the tuple - it would have still worked with the tuple as you had it. But you just happen to not need it and python makes it easy to iterate over the characters of a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tuple` is not necessary in this situation because your dictionary will handle assigning the keys to the associated strings.

```
num = input("Enter a number here: ")

numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
for n in num:
    print(numWords[n], end=' ')
```

Demo:

```
Enter a number here: 456
Four Five Six
```

Comment: The list seems no more necessary than the tuple.

Comment: Might want to also add some 'splainin'.

Comment: Thank you, this does the job! I was unclear on the purpose of a tuple and thought I had to use one for this process.

Comment: true, @pvg I didn't expect this to work in comparison to the other answers, will try to include some verbage :)

Comment: @downshift, `num` return a string, in order to use it for indexing a dictionary, it need to be converted to int first. Therefore `print(numWords[n])` should be `print(numWords[int(n)], end = ' ')`.

Comment: @hcheung, that would be necessary if the keys were integers, but the OP's dictionary uses strings

Comment: @downshift it helps when you get a stampede of bad answers :)

Comment: @beary, you may have been considering using the `tuple` as `(num, str_val)`, but indeed the dictionary does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the `type` of the keys of your dict and the input after you convert it to a tuple with `tuple(num)`.
You could either just skip the part where you convert to tuple:

```
num = input("Enter number here: ")
num = input("Enter a number here: ")
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
print(numWords[num])
```

OR

index into the tuple and access the element by picking the 0th element:

```
num = input("Enter number here: ")
num = input("Enter a number here: ")
numTup = tuple(num)
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
print(numWords[numTup[0]])
```

**NOTE:** Make sure the datatype of the keys and the variable you are using to access the dict items is the same. You can check the data type of a variable with the `type()` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
'''
You can print the number in words given irs numeric
version if by defining your dictionary with
the following format:
    dict{'number': 'word'}

Then, calling the dictionary as follows:
    dict['number']
'''

# Number (keys) and words (values) dictionary
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", 
'3': "Three", '4': "Four", 
'5': "Five", '6': "Six", 
'7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", 
'9': "Nine", '10': "Ten"}

# Function that prints the number in words
def print_values():
    for k,v in numWords.items():
        print(v)

'''
Alternatively, if you want to print a value using
its key as an argument, you can use the following
funciton:
'''

# Interactive function to print number in words
# given the number
def print_values2():
    key = input("What number would you like to print? ")
    print(numWords[key])

'''
P.s. if you want to add a number to your dictionary
you can use the following function
'''

# Function to modify numWords
def add_number():

    # Specify the number you want to add
    numeric = input("Type in the number: ")

    # Input the number in words
    word = input("Write the number in words: ")

    # Assign number and word to dictionary
    numWords[numeric] = word

    # Return modified dictionary
    return numWords
```

Comment: This reads a bit like the parody enterprise solution to this question.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear why you want to turn the number into tuple but in case you want that, you did in a wrong way. when you want to create a tuple from an int you should do the following:

```
numTup = (num)
```

And your full code should looks like:

```
num = input("Enter a number here: ")
numTup = (num)
numWords = {'1': "One", '2': "Two", '3': "Three", '4': "Four", '5': "Five", '6': "Six", '7': "Seven", '8': "Eight", '9': "Nine"}
print(numWords[numTup])
```